# Asp.net mvc editor file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I made according to official website a kendo editor. I met a problem with file uploading, is there any command to select file from pc and save it on server?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
      .Name("editor")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;height:440px" })
      .Tools(tools => tools
          .Clear()
          .InsertImage()
          .InsertFile()
          .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
          .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
          .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList()
          .Outdent().Indent()
          .CreateLink().Unlink()
          .SubScript()
          .SuperScript()
          .TableEditing()
          .Formatting()
          .CleanFormatting()
          .FontName()
          .FontSize()
          .FontColor().BackColor()
          .Print())
      .Value(@<text>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Html)</text>)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Kendo Upload widget. Take a look at the samples [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index).